# IBM Websphere plugin issue - iisWASPlugin_http.dll Out-of-process ISAPI extension request failed

Tags: iis-6, isapi, websphere-8

I attempts to setup IIS (version 6.0, windows 2003 server) sit in front of IBM WAS server so that it can route all specific traffic to IBM WebSphere application server. I've things setup on both UAT and pre-production IIS web server and its works just fine. The problem happens now, however, only in production server. I investigated the websphere plugin logs (defined in plugin-cfg.xml) and found the following errors

iisWASPlugin_http.dll  Out-of-process ISAPI extension request failed.

Tried google the solution but no luck.

Setup procedures is summarized below

1. Install IBM Installation Manager
2. Install Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server and Version 8.5.0.0 through IBM Installation Manager
3. Copy Plugin-cfg.xml, Plugin-key.db, Plugin-key.sth from WAS to web server.
4. Configurate IIS web site - create virtual directory named sePlugins, Add ISAPI filter with iisWASPlugin_http.dl, add Web service extension
5. Create plugin-cfg.loc, paste the full path of plugin-cfg.xml to plugin-cfg.loc

The procedures above already working in UAT and pre-production environment.

Details setup procedures is exactly the same as the url below

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftins_manualWebIIS.html

(Refer to "Configure IIS Version 6.0." section)

Note: IIS have "IIS 5.0 isolation mode" turned on.

Any help / hints is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: How did you generate plugin-cfg.xml? I am facing some issues configuring IIS with websphere? Please help me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715719/how-to-configure-iis-with-ibm-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile

Comment: There are couples way. This ibm technote should help http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207587

Comment: I have setup WAS8.5 and Mobile First 7 on my local machine. After following all the steps when I hit localhost/worklightconsole, IIs is throwing me an error : 
HTTP Error 502.4 - Bad Gateway
No appropriate server could be found to route the request.

Comment: if you could post your plugin-cfg.xml it might help

Comment: I have edited my question and posted my plugin-cfg.xml : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715719/how-to-configure-iis-with-ibm-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error gone after a server reboot...